# How to Access AppData Folder

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp

i looked at every question in SO, but i dont found any solution for my Problem.

I want to Access the Appdata Folder like this:

```
 Storagefolder foldertree = 
    await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"C:\Users\Username\AppData");
```

Actually i use the Spring Update so i can Target every Folder but not the AppData.

I know that the reason is that the Folder is hidden.

So anyone got a solution the Access hidden Folders?

Comment: Are you trying to access your own app's data ? if yes , have you tried this ? `Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = 
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;`

Comment: No, i want to Access this Folder from my Path if it is possible.

Comment: Have you tried accessing it through URI e.g. `ms-appdata:///local/myFile.txt`. Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalFolder) for more details.

Comment: I dont think you can access every folder atleast by this documentation. Im not sure about the spring update. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions

Answer (score 1):

Universal Windows Apps (apps) can access certain file system locations by default. Apps can also access additional locations through the file picker, or by declaring capabilities

> *You can try using file picker and navigate to folder. But im sure you need the app to pickup file automatically without filepicker*

- **Application install directory.** The folder where your app is installed on the user’s system.
  `Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;`
- **Application data locations**. The folders where your app can store data. These folders (local, roaming and temporary) are created when your app is installed.

  `using Windows.Storage;
  StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;`
- **User’s Downloads folder**. The folder where downloaded files are saved by default.
  App can only access files and folders in the user's Downloads folder that your app created. However, you can gain access to files and folders in the user's Downloads folder by calling a file picker (FileOpenPicker or FolderPicker) so that users can navigate and pick files or folders for your app to access.

[File Access Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)